# Can I just insert JavaScript by using <script>?

Tags: javascript

I am very new to build Wordpress Website, so please bear with me if I don't describe things properly.

There is a website providing the .js file for flying bats on the screen.
https://www.delphitools.info/2013/10/30/pimp-your-website-with-an-halloween-bat/

It says that I can just insert the script by using

```
<script async src="https://cdn.delphitools.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/jsbat.js"></script>
```

but it doesn't work on the website.

What did I do wrong? Do I have to change something in the JS file?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where did you insert it? And did you follow the instructions and upload the file?

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I did download the file and use the plugin called "Header and Footer Script" to insert in Header by using <script async src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/jsbat.js"></script>. I do check the location on Media but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

### Note: you should use child theme ( here I'll reference main theme )

I believe you've downloaded that jsbat.js file somewhere in your wordpress root directory
consider this your root directory of web

```
/xampp/htdocs/wordpress_site/wp-content/themes/theme-name/assets/js/jsbat.js
```

now you'll need to find functions.php file in your theme. Typically this resides in this folder:

```
/xampp/htdocs/wordpress_site/wp-content/themes/theme-name/functions.php
```

edit functions.php file, and add following code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fy_load_scripts' );
function fy_load_scripts(){
       wp_enqueue_script( 'jsbat-script-js', get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/js/jsbat.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
```

this is just generalized answer, please modify ( you won't need to create function 'fy_load_scripts' but in case you don't know what to do just copy and paste the code in functions.php file and the directory structure should be matched as well )

Hope this helps
Good luck!

Comment: I tried this in my localhost, it works but funny thing is I can only see one bat
:)

Comment: Thank you Maverick. I am still trying it as I am really new to wordpress. :-) I did check where there are so many bats in that website. All we need to do is just duplicate the script to 3 or more, and we can see more bats on the screen. I did try it on my own test HTML. It worked in my <html><head><body> type of webpage. :-)

Comment: If your site is live, use child theme instead: this will give you a brief introduction to child theme and how to create them https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme/

Comment: Hi Maverick, is the "/assets/js/jsbat.js" in the script code the location of where I keep the file I downloaded? Can I change it to /wp-content/uploads/2018/10/jsbat.js. does that make sense?

Comment: @Dan No need to upload via media upload as described by the script author. If you are calling your script correctly, then it will work fine. Just tested locally.

Comment: @KashifRafique Thank you for your reply. I have done other scripts before and they worked. I will keep trying to figure out what the problem is. Thanks for everyone who answered this question for me. :-)